# how to always display busy/spinning cursor when opening apps?

Tags: cursor

The busy cursor does not show up when I open an application like vlc, firefox etc..
So, a lot of times, I end up opening multiple instances of an app.
I don't seem to find any setting to force display busy cursor on opening apps.
Is there a tweak to enable it?
I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS default DE; i.e. gnome